# Bash sort by character position in column

Tags: bash, sorting

I would like to sort the below file by the 2nd column, from the 7th position to the 9th position.

```
$ cat sample.bed
chr1    248956422       chr1:248956422
chr2    242193529       chr2:242193529
chr3    198295559       chr3:198295559
chr4    190214555       chr4:190214555
chr5    181538259       chr5:181538259
chr6    170805979       chr6:170805979
chr7    159345973       chr7:159345973
chrX    156040895       chrX:156040895
chr8    145138636       chr8:145138636
chr9    138394717       chr9:138394717
```

I use sort as shown and get the below output:

```
$ sort -n -k2.7,2.9 sample.bed
chr4    190214555       chr4:190214555
chr6    170805979       chr6:170805979
chr5    181538259       chr5:181538259
chr2    242193529       chr2:242193529
chr8    145138636       chr8:145138636
chrX    156040895       chrX:156040895
chr3    198295559       chr3:198295559
chr9    138394717       chr9:138394717
chr1    248956422       chr1:248956422
chr7    159345973       chr7:159345973
```

Sort changes the row order, but not based on my parameters. Note that sort -k2,2 works as expected:

```
$ sort -k2,2 sample.bed
chr9    138394717       chr9:138394717
chr8    145138636       chr8:145138636
chrX    156040895       chrX:156040895
chr7    159345973       chr7:159345973
chr6    170805979       chr6:170805979
chr5    181538259       chr5:181538259
chr4    190214555       chr4:190214555
chr3    198295559       chr3:198295559
chr2    242193529       chr2:242193529
chr1    248956422       chr1:248956422
```

I must be missing something obvious... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `sort --debug` is very informative:

```
# sort -n -k2.7,2.9 --debug
...
chr4    190214555       chr4:190214555
          ___
______________________________________
...
```

It compares `021` from the first `chr4` line, because it counts the leading blanks as belonging to the field. You can:

```
sort -n -k2.11,2.13
```

or ignore leading blanks with `-b`:

```
sort -b -n -k2.7,2.9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and for pointing out the useful debug feature!

Comment: If the second field is not fixed-length, how should I modify so that it's sorted by the last 3 digits in the second field?

Comment: No idea, I don't think "last 3 digits" is possible. I would pass it via `sed` and extract last 3 digits.